# Run SQL statements asynchronously

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have six SQL UPDATE statements (on the same database) as an SQL Agent job that I run every night to ensure that two systems are in sync with each other.  Each update takes about 10 minutes to run.

As a test today I opened SQL Studio Manager and opened five windows and ran the five updates concurrently (I can guarantee that a row can only ever be updated by one SQL statement).  The five queries ran in 15 minutes.

Therefore instead of using a single SQL Agent Job I am thinking about calling the SQL statements from a VB.NET program, so that I can either:

1) Use asynchronous calls to ensure the queries are running concurrently.
2) Use multiple threads to ensure the queries are running concurrently

I read an article recently that says that asynchronous calls should not be used to speed up processing performance.  Therefore I believe that multiple threads is the answer.  Is that correct?

Comment: Why not 5 agent jobs?

Comment: Multiple threads should be fine as long as concurrency of the data is not an issue. Or use multiple jobs.

Comment: You could also run them concurrently from an SSIS package if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

> I read an article recently that says that asynchronous calls should not be used to speed up processing performance. Therefore I believe that multiple threads is the answer. Is that correct?

I think either what you read is wrong, or you've misinterpreted it. Running things concurrently will not speed that thing up, but will allow more things to happen in parallel by freeing up threads (on Windows threads are expensive to create: creating and destroying them over short periods should be avoided).

Concurrency (eg. using .NET 4.5.1's async support) allows the activity, including starting other asynchronous actions, to continue while the thread is used for something else.

The details of how to do this depend on how you are accessing the database: Entity Framework (EF), ADO.NET, or something else?

With EF you can use the extension methods in `QueryableExtensions` like [`ToListAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220257%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) on queries.

With ADO.NET you can use `SqlCommand` methods like [`ExecuteNonQueryAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223678%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ExecuteReaderAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executereaderasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I am using ADO.NET.  +1 for reference to ExecuteReaderAsync etc.

Answer (score 1):

since you are dealing with a sql statement the choice you make in vb.net will not affect the performances or the time required to complete the 5 tasks on sql.

if you make 5 async calls then you will sit waiting for 5 answers; if you spawn 5 threads these threads will sit waiting for their syncronous calls to finish. the net result will be the same.

me too i'm pushing for the 5 agent jobs: is a solution that leverages existing sql tools, does not requires additional coding (more coding = more maintenance) and is available out of the box on almost any sql instance.